# Does not see all RAM

Tags: release-hera

For some reason, it doesn't see all the RAM. My laptop has 8gb installed[image]

Comment: How is your RAM configured? Is it 4 x 2 GB sticks?

Comment: 4gb x 2 sticks, 

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0012
 Error Information Handle: 0x0018
 Total Width: 64 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 4096 MB
 Form Factor: SODIMM
Handle 0x001C, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x0012
 Error Information Handle: 0x001B
 Total Width: 64 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 4096 MB
 Form Factor: SODIMM

Comment: I've seen this before where 1/2 of a stick of RAM goes bad while the rest works just fine. Have you considered running memtest to see if there's a hardware issue? That'd be what I would do personally as my next step. RAM is dual-sided and half can go bad, it's just really rare. It sometimes crops up on the AskUbuntu part of this site.